# I need the length of a NSRegularExpression result string

Tags: objective-c, regex, string, nsregularexpression

I have a many files where some of them have timestamp prefixes like this:

```
1 20160308 1340 - All-of-me_key.pdf
2 2016 05 15 00 45 - nobody-knows-you-when-you-are-down-and-out.pdf
```

Others don´t have prefixes:

```
- praying-for-time_key.pdf
- purple rain.pdf
- rehab.pdf
```

The format of the prefixes is varying. Some have blanks as seperators and others have dashes as you can see above.

I want to automate a process to remove the prefixes from file names concerned.

For the purpose of this explanation I created two regex patterns:

```
    atRegexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                @"[0-9]{8} +[0-9]{4} - ",
                @"[0-9]{4} +[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2} - ", nil ] ;
```

The first one detects prefixes of the first type and the second pattern detects prefixes of the second type.

Example for the first type detection:

```
NSString * patternString = @"[0-9]{8} +[0-9]{4} - " ;
NSString *)theFileName   = @"20160308 1340 - All-of-me_key.pdf" ;

NSString *string = theFileName;
NSError *error = NULL;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:patternString
                                   options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                   error:&error];

NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:theFileName
                             options:0
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [theFileName length])];
```

Detection works fine. The problem is, I need the length of the prefix.
In this example the length of "20160308 1340 - " is 16
In example2 the length of "2016 05 15 00 45 - " is 19

I don´t see how to geht this length automatically.

Any idea?

Comment: do you need **[this](https://regex101.com/r/jD7qR2/1)**?

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want the string after the prefix, you can use capturing parentheses for that. And if you want to match on a number of specific number patterns, then just include those different patterns separated by `|`. For example:

```
NSArray *strings = @[@"20160308 1340 - All-of-me_key.pdf",
                     @"2016 05 15 00 45 - nobody-knows-you-when-you-are-down-and-out.pdf",
                     @"- praying-for-time_key.pdf"];

NSString *patternString = @"^(\\d{8} \\d{4} |\\d{4} \\d{2} \\d{2} \\d{2} \\d{2} )?(.*)$";

NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:patternString
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:&error];

for (NSString *string in strings) {
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
    if (match) {
        NSLog(@"length of prefix = %ld", (long)[match rangeAtIndex:1].length);
        NSLog(@"stringAfterPrefix = '%@'", [string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]]);
    }
}
```

That results in:

```
length of prefix = 14
stringAfterPrefix = '- All-of-me_key.pdf'

length of prefix = 17
stringAfterPrefix = '- nobody-knows-you-when-you-are-down-and-out.pdf'

length of prefix = 0
stringAfterPrefix = '- praying-for-time_key.pdf'
```

There are lots of permutations on this idea (allowing for variable number of space characters after the prefix, stripping the leading dash off too, etc.), but hopefully this illustrates the basic idea of using capturing parentheses to find the text in question, and the use of `|` to match on potentially mutiple different prefixes.